# Does Postgres have an equilvalent of MySQL's collations?

Tags: postgresql, collation

MySQL has a [big long list of collations](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/), but I can't find whether Postgres has something analogous. Is there something similar that Postgres has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from [this page from the 9.1 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html) this looks like a forthcoming feature. With currently stable releases, it's a per-cluster configuration option. You can read more about this situation [here](http://simononsoftware.com/postgresql-collation/).

Comment: It's per database, not per cluster. Check the CREATE DATABASE statement: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-createdatabase.html

Comment: There are other restrictions that make it not quite that free though. You can't mix-and-match encodings and collations, for example, and unless you're copying template0 you must use the same collation and encoding as the template, which defaults to template1.

Comment: It WAS per cluster way back when, but that changed around 8.2 or so.